# ExtJS persistent panels (no autoDestroy)

Tags: extjs, panel, removeall

Good evening dear fellow programmers!

I have a question regarding persistant panels in ExtJS. I have a few form panels that I want to display inside a single container panel. The displayed form depends on the type of object that the user is editing. As far as I understand, this can be achieved by the following 3 statements:

- removeAll(true)
- add(persistent form panel)
- doLayout()

The problem is that this doesn't seem to work. If using 2 different persistent form panels, they both stick to the container panel. The strange thing is that it does seem to work when I don't use persistent panels, but recreate the form panels every time I add them to the container:

- removeAll(true)
- add(new form panel())
- doLayout()

See a working example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  Ext.namespace("Ext.ARA");

  Ext.onReady(function()
  {
    Ext.ARA.AddFormPanelDoesntWorkA = function()
    {
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.removeAll(false);
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.add(Ext.ARA.FormPanelA);
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.doLayout();
    }

    Ext.ARA.AddFormPanelDoesntWorkB = function()
    {
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.removeAll(false);
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.add(Ext.ARA.FormPanelB);
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.doLayout();
    }

    Ext.ARA.AddFormPanelDoesWorkA = function()
    {
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.removeAll(true);
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.add(new Ext.form.FormPanel({title:'Form Panel A', padding:5, items:[new Ext.form.TextField({fieldLabel:'Panel A Field', anchor:'100%'})]}));
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.doLayout();
    }

    Ext.ARA.AddFormPanelDoesWorkB = function()
    {
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.removeAll(true);
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.add(new Ext.form.FormPanel({title:'Form Panel B', padding:5, items:[new Ext.form.TextField({fieldLabel:'Panel B Field', anchor:'100%'})]}));
      Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel.doLayout();
    }

    Ext.ARA.FormPanelA = new Ext.form.FormPanel({title:'Form Panel A', padding:5, items:[new Ext.form.TextField({fieldLabel:'Panel A Field', anchor:'100%'})]});
    Ext.ARA.FormPanelB = new Ext.form.FormPanel({title:'Form Panel B', padding:5, items:[new Ext.form.TextField({fieldLabel:'Panel B Field', anchor:'100%'})]});

    Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel = new Ext.Panel
    ({
      title:'Container Panel',
      bbar:new Ext.Toolbar
      ({
        items:
        [
          {text:'AddFormPanelDoesntWorkA', handler:Ext.ARA.AddFormPanelDoesntWorkA}, 
          {text:'AddFormPanelDoesntWorkB', handler:Ext.ARA.AddFormPanelDoesntWorkB}, '->',
          {text:'AddFormPanelDoesWorkA', handler:Ext.ARA.AddFormPanelDoesWorkA}, 
          {text:'AddFormPanelDoesWorkB', handler:Ext.ARA.AddFormPanelDoesWorkB}
        ]
      })
    });

    Ext.ARA.Mainframe = new Ext.Viewport({layout:'fit', items:[Ext.ARA.ContainerPanel]});
  });
</script>
```

What is the proper way to use persistent form panels in ExtJS? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and made a few tweaks and didn't get it to work and then I realised that I'd have used a [CardLayout](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.layout.CardLayout) for this sort of display. See the [LayoutBrowser](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) where it is demonstrated using a 'Wizard' type of display. I think it'll give you what you need.